# elevateZoom add another picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I downloaded the elevate zoom demo but when i add a 5th image the zoom function doesn't change the image it zooms in on. It worked fine when I only had 4 images and i cant find what is causing it.

Here is the main body, i put the css etc in the html at the moment until i manage to fix it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>jQuery elevateZoom Demo</title>
    <script src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>

    <style>
    /*set a border on the images to prevent shifting*/
 #gallery_01 img{border:2px solid white;}

 /*Change the colour*/
 .active img{border:2px solid #333 !important;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<img id="zoom_03" src="images/small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="images/large/image1.jpg"/>

<div id="gallery_01">

  <a href="#" data-image="images/small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="images/large/image1.jpg">
    <img id="zoom_03" src="images/thumb/image1.jpg" />
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-image="images/small/image2.png" data-zoom-image="images/large/image2.jpg">
    <img id="zoom_03" src="images/thumb/image2.jpg" />
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-image="images/small/image3.png" data-zoom-image="images/large/image3.jpg">
    <img id="zoom_03" src="images/thumb/image3.jpg" />
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-image="images/small/image4.png" data-zoom-image="images/large/image4.jpg">
    <img id="zoom_03" src="images/thumb/image4.jpg" />
  </a>

    <a href="#" data-image="images/small/image5.png" data-zoom-image="images/large/image5.jpg">
    <img id="zoom_03" src="images/thumb/image5.jpg" />
  </a>


</div>

<script>
//initiate the plugin and pass the id of the div containing gallery images
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true, loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'}); 

//pass the images to Fancybox
$("#zoom_03").bind("click", function(e) {  
  var ez =   $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom'); 
    $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
  return false;
});
</script>


<script>
    $('#zoom_03').elevateZoom({

zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
   }); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the main code was taken from this site
[here](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom)

the function I'm trying is the Gallery & Lightbox one

Comment: I'm not sure if this is specifically your issue but you shouldn't have multiple elements on your page with the same id. If you need to address multiple elements, use a class.

Comment: the id is only there to replace the 1st image as i want the main image to change. the js changes zoom_03 for me. Ive played around with it for quite a while and i managed to kinda make it work. the images zoom function would sometimes work and it sometimes wont. it confuses me since all it takes sometimes is a refresh with no code changes

Comment: Either way, you should change the IDs of each image to be different and use a class to target all of the images, just to rule out this causing a problem.

Comment: I've just tried that but the problem still occurs

Comment: You're calling .elevateZoom twice - on every image. That doesn't make sense. If I understand what you want correctly, you should only be calling it on the active image as it's loaded. Also, this example seems to be missing the fancybox JS file.